# Select query return values with two white spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to separate LastName from the Firstname of AccountName as shown below.

| ID | AccountName | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dos Santos Albert | Dos Santos | Albert |
| 2 | Del Pierro Martin | Del Pierro | Martin |
| 3 | Del Castillo Johannes | Del Castillo | Johannes |
| 4 | Del Rio Wilbert | Del Rio | Wilbert |

So far I have this code

```
SELECT  
    Accountname,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(AccountName, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', AccountName ) = 0 THEN LEN(AccountName) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', AccountName) -1 END),' ',
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(AccountName, CHARINDEX(' ',AccountName) + 1, LEN(AccountName)),CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(AccountName, CHARINDEX(' ', AccountName) + 1, LEN(AccountName))))) AS 'LastName',
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(AccountName, CHARINDEX(' ',AccountName) + 1, LEN(AccountName)),CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(AccountName, CHARINDEX(' ', AccountName) + 1, LEN(AccountName)))) AS 'FirstName'      
FROM [Accounts]
```

Comment: Good luck... this is why you should never store your data like this.

Comment: So far whats not working with you query?

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). This is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query,

Simple trick will resolve your issue,
For first name, I'm just getting the last past of the name by the index of space from reverse.

For Last name, using the extracted first name column, I'm replacing the value from AccountName column, this will resolve your Lase name without using indexes

```
SELECT RIGHT(AccountName , CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE(AccountName))-1) as First_Name,
REPLACE
(AccountName, RIGHT(AccountName , CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE(AccountName))-1), '') as Last_Name;
```

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=568cb12e-77ae-4bfb-ab0c-75388e846fe3

```
SELECT RIGHT('Dos Santos Albert' , CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE('Dos Santos Albert'))-1) as First_Name,
REPLACE
('Dos Santos Albert', RIGHT('Dos Santos Albert' , CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE('Dos Santos Albert'))-1), '') as Last_Name
```

[image]